# Sort List of Fixmes by annotation level

Tags: sorting, fixme

I have a couple of questions about the `fixme` package:

- I would like the list of fixmes printed using `\listoffixmes` to be sort by annotation level (that is, sorted by importance). Is there a way to do this?
- Can I change the color scheme of the notes?
- How do I change the name of the list of fixmes to something else (other than "Corrections"). I am able to add the list to the ToC.

Comment: For sorting by levels I think that is not useful, but may be [todonotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Colours are answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179514/customizing-inline-coloring-with-the-fixme-package

Comment: Changing name of the list of fixmes should just be redefining `\englishlistfixmename` (or whatever language you're in). It's documented in the manual.