# Customizing inline coloring with the fixme package

Tags: color, fixme

How can I set the color of annotated `fixme` text (not the comment itself)?

This MWE produces the text under consideration in a blueish color, that is hard to read, I'd like it to be darker and more alarming (or just red).

```
% Run with: pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color}

\begin{document}
Hello \fxnote*{Should this be capitalized?}{world}!
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Screen shot]

This other question shows how to deal with the coloring of the first argument in annotated fixme (the comment itself), but what about the second argument (the text which is under consideration. [Fixme package fxnote background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68570/fixme-package-fxnote-background)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, see p. 16 of the manual and proceed:

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}


\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color}
\definecolor{fxtarget}{rgb}{0.8000,0.0000,0.0000}

\begin{document}
Hello \fxnote*{Should this be capitalized?}{world}!
\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image]

Comment: I've trawled the documentation several times, but yet it escaped me! Good job!

Comment: Since I have a predefined color I wish to use called primary, I substitute the line with \colorlet{fxtarget}{primary}. This was not part of the question, just wanted to state this, if others needed it as well :)

Comment: @Clausen »I've trawled the documentation several times...« Yes, it took quite a while to find it. I've never heard before of fixme, as far as I remember. But I was interested in the package, as I often have to correct texts as well. But probably the package does not support pagebreaks inside annotations in the margin. So I'll have to write some lines myself to do it with the new package `scrlayer-notecolumn`. Hm, an addition of fixme would be really nice.